# Wiring 2 gang light switches

Tags: wiring

I have a two gang box with a dimmer switch to recessed lights AND a remote switch to operate a fan/light.  There are 3 romex bundles leading into the box, however, only one of the black wires is HOT, one apparently does nothing, and one leads to  BOTH the recessed lights AND the fan/light fixtures.

I removed the remote switch a couple years ago when it stopped responding, and do not recall how it was wired previously.  Any help here would be appreciated.  Happy to further elaborate.  For reference, I have a included a picture of a similar two gang box setup, and the specific box with switches removed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do/did you have a switched outlet on that wall as well? I assume the other pair of cables could be a run to another room, switch or outlets in the same or adjoining room. Any outlets or switches in this or adjacent room(s) that don't work?

Comment: No there is no switched outlet.  My current theory is somehow the third black wire became depowered and is no longer HOT. ??????